# Android - Get key if data exists (Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In one of my activities I insert some data to the Firebase database. In another activity I want to check if the child of the inserted data exists. If the key exists I want to get the root unique key.

**Problem:**
I have this database structure:

[image]

I want to check if the **username** child exists. If it exists I want to get the root key. Both the root unique key and the username node is marked with red.

**What I have done**

```
  //variable username is the actual username of the current user
    userRef.child(sharedPreferences.getString("school", null)).child("routes").orderByChild("username").equalTo(username).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String key=ds.getKey();
                    System.out.println("key" + key);
                }
        }
```

But I don't now how to get inside the drivers node, and how to get the root unique key. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You can pass in a path to `orderByChild()` to filter on the property at that path. So:

```
userRef.child(sharedPreferences.getString("school", null))
       .child("routes").orderByChild("drivers/username").equalTo(username).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

Now your `onDataChange` will get called with a snapshot of all nodes that have the required user name. So looping over them and printing is the same as you had:

```
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key=ds.getKey();
            System.out.println("key" + key);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, using `exists()` method.

```
userRef.child("routes").child(routeId).child("drivers").child(userName).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                //do something
            } 
    }
```

If you want to verify the existents of `username` accross all routes, assuming that `routes` node is a direct child of your Firebase database, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference routesRef = rootRef.child("routes");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if(ds.child("drivers").child(userName).exists()) {
                //do what you want
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
routesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

In which `userName` is the name of the user that you want to be checked for existent.

Comment: I don't have the routeId. That is the problem.

Comment: But you can get it. The simplest way to have that id is to get and store it in the moment you are generating it using the push() method like this: `String routeId = yourRef.push().getKey();` Having that key, you can use it easely in your DatabaseReference.

Comment: But what if the username child is not present in that particular routeId, but another routeId. Because I have many routes, which is each identified with the routeId. What routeId does it store in the `routeId` variable?

Comment: I tried printing inside the `if-statement`, but it does not print anything.

Comment: A possible reason could be that the `DatabaseReference ` is incorrect. If you try to print `Log("TAG", ds.child("drivers").child("username").getRef().toString());` is the real path?

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(ds.hasChild("drivers")){
           String key=ds.getKey();    
            }
```

you can do this:

```
userRef.child("routes").orderByChild("username").equalTo("jju").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...){ //code here }
```

edit:

```
 userRef.child("routes").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               if(ds.hasChild("driver"){
                for(DataSnapshot data : ds.getChildren()){
                    if(data.child("username").exists()){
                String key=ds.getKey();
                System.out.println("key" + key);
                  }
                }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This gives me all the keys with the child `drivers` in them. Is it possible to check if the child `username` exists?

Comment: you can do the above @JDoe

Comment: For some reason this does not return the key.

Comment: what does it return then?

Comment: It returns nothing. I have updated my post. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what is this `child(sharedPreferences.getString("school", null))`? `DatabaseReference userRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()` then userRef.child("routes").. then everything else

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that. The `child(sharedPreferences.getString("school", null))` is my root node

Comment: the root node should be there by default and it shouldnt be in a child()..

Comment: Okay, I removed it and tried again. It still don't work

Comment: This does not print out anything.

Comment: It still does not print anything.